# How to remove a deleted question from my following list?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

This question is showed as `deleted` in my following list. So I can not open and read it. Then how could I remove it from the list?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560686/using-rowcolor-with-csvsimple-and-longtable-always-prompts-no-align-error

Comment: Not sure, but try going to `https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/106776/l-j-r?tab=following` (i.e. the "Following" tab in your user profile), then in the list, you should see an `Unfollow` link/button...

Comment: Ah, I can only see the Unfollow button in desktop browsers. The button is missing in mobile browsers. Thank you!

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346423/how-do-i-unfollow-a-deleted-question

Comment: @L.J.R.: By "mobile browsers" are you referring to the Stack Exchange app, or actually a browser you're running on your mobile device? If it's the latter, what browser are you running that doesn't show this button (I can see "Follow" in Chrome, so I assume it will also allow me to Unfollow).

Comment: I am using builtin mobile browser on my Android phone. The UserAgent is `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; KOZ-AL00 Build/HONORKOZ-AL00; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile Safari/537.36`